How can I achieve double tap back button exit using PopScope in Flutter?
I am trying to enhance the user experience by preventing accidental app exits. If users press the back button once, they should see a toast message saying, "Press again to exit." If they press the back button again within 2 seconds, the app should exit. If more than 2 seconds pass, the app should reset the back button by pressing the counter.

What do you mean by the back button? The one in the AppBar, a custom one or the one of the phone? What have you tried so far?

I made a tutorial on use of Popscope  which will help you - https://youtu.be/W9ihZAFBjpQ
I also have another tutorial which you can use as an alternative and it really works -  https://youtu.be/rShYGZoCFxs

Consider I am on the Home screen with a bottom navigation. I don't have an app bar back button. I have only a system back button provided by my smartphone. I need to handle that.

Try PopScope as below
DateTime? currentBackPressTime;
bool canPopNow = false;

  PopScope(
  canPop: canPopNow,
  onPopInvokedWithResult: (didPop, dynamic) {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    if (currentBackPressTime == null || now.difference(currentBackPressTime!) > const Duration(seconds: 2)) {
      currentBackPressTime = now;
      setState(() {
        canPopNow = false;
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        canPopNow = true;
      });
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => YourPreviousPage()));
      });
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(//your widgets)


This should work. Let me know if it works for you.
You can a achieve a "double back press for exit" with a Future and a ValueNotifier.
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyScreen> createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  final ValueNotifier<bool> _backPressAllowed = ValueNotifier(false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
      valueListenable: _backPressAllowed,
      builder: (BuildContext context, bool backPressAllowed, Widget? child) {
        return PopScope(
          canPop: backPressAllowed,
          onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
            if (!didPop) {
              _allowBackPress();
            }
          },
          child: const Scaffold(
            body: Text("my screen"),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _allowBackPress() async {
    _backPressAllowed.value = true;

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));

    _backPressAllowed.value = false;
  }
}


Can I do without  ValueListenableBuilder?

Here's the professional way to achieve this:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvokedWithResult: (didPop, result) async {
        {
          if (didPop) {
            return;
          }
          final shouldPop = await _showBackDialog() ?? false;
          if (context.mounted && shouldPop == true) {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
       // Your scaffold code
      ),
    );
  }

Future<bool?> _showBackDialog() {
    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: const Text(
            'Your progress will be lost if you leave now. Do you really want to stop exercising?',
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Keep Going'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, false);
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text(
                'Leave',
                style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, true);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

